# Javascript: Detecting specific word in the text box?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a short quiz game (where they guess the correct character name), and I'm trying to figure out how I could switch to a different div once the user presses enter, as they guessed the correct word (which is typed on the text field)

I know my js is wrong and is missing the part where it detects the correct word, i just can't seem to figure it out

HTML:

```
  <div id="ques1" class="ques">
   <img src="img/img1.png" alt="">

    <div id="btncontainer" class="btncontainer">
      <input id="txtbox" placeholder="Type here"/>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="ques2" class="ques">
   <img src="img/img2.png" alt="">
  </div>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownEnter)

function keyDownEnter(e) {
 var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==13) {
   ques1.style.display = 'none';
   ques2.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: In your code, you are switching to different divs not screens or pages.

Comment: yes i mean divs sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function keyDownEnter(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==13) {
                   document.getElementById("quest1").style.display = 'none';
                     document.getElementById("quest2").style.display = 'block';
        } 
    }
```

Comment: It works! but is this jQuery? not sure what the (e) /e.keyCode is

Comment: e is the event captured. e.keyCode is the value that you clicked, suppose for example  you type A it's keyCode will be 65. And this is pure javascript no jquery